# Fortran: odd space-padding string behavior when opening files

Tags: string, fortran, whitespace

I have a Fortran program which reads data from a bunch of input files. The first file contains, among other things, the names of three other files that I will read from, specified in the input file (which I redirect to `stdin` at execution of the program) as follows

```
"data/file_1.dat" "data/file2.dat" "data/file_number_3.txt"
```

They're separated by regular spaces and there's no trailing spaces on the line, just a line break. I read the file names like this:

```
character*30 fnames(3)
read *, fnames
```

and then I proceed to read the data, through calling on a function which takes the file name as parameter:

```
subroutine read_from_data_file(fname)
    implicit none
    character*(*) fname

    open(15,file=fname)
    ! read some data
end subroutine read_from_data_file

! in the main program:
do i=1,3
    call read_from_data_file(trim(fnames(i)))
end do
```

For the **third file**, regardless of in which order I put the file names in the input file, the padding doesn't work and Fortran tries to open a with a name like "data/file_number_3.txt                ", i.e. with a bunch of trailing spaces. This creates an empty file named `data/file_number_3.txt (White Space Conflict)` in my folder, and as soon as I try to read from the file the program crashes with an EOF error.

I've tried adding `trim()` in various places, e.g. `open(15,file=trim(fname))` without any success. I assume it has something to do with the fix length of character arrays in Fortran, but I thought `trim()` would take care of that - is that assumption incorrect?

How do I troubleshoot and fix this?

Comment: Note that reading unix paths with list directed input (the `*` in the read statement) is asking for trouble, as an unquoted `/` has special meaning for that sort of input - it terminates input processing.  You might get away with it here because of the quoting, but if those quotes got stripped for any reason (say by the shell) then you are going to see garbage in the second and subsequent items being read.

Comment: @IanH: Thanks for the heads-up - yet another thing I know to look for if (when) things go south... but so far I've had no problems, so unless you have a good suggestion on what to do instead I think I'll keep doing this. After all, I got it working again =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm.  I wonder if there is a final character on the last line of your input file which is not whitespace, such as an EOF marker from a Linux system popping up on a Windows system or *vice-versa*.  Try, if you are on a Linux box, `dos2unix`; on a Windows box try something else (I'm not sure what).

If that doesn't work, try using the intrinsic `IACHAR` function to examine each individual character in the misbehaving string and examine the entrails.

Like you, I expect `trim` to trim trailing whitespace from a string, but not all the characters which are not displayed are regarded as whitespace.

And, while I'm writing, your use of declarations such as

```
character*30
```

is obsolescent, the modern alternative is

```
character(len=30)
```

and

```
character(len=*)
```

is preferred to

```
character*(*)
```

**EDIT**

Have you tried both reading those names from a file and reading them from `stdin` ?

Comment: `dos2unix` didn't make any difference, so I'm trying to use `iachar()` for diagnostics. However, I can't figure out how to extract a character from the character array: `fname = fnames(1)` gives me the first file name, but `fname(1)` gives me a syntax error on the opening parenthesis whenever I try to use it. `fname` is declared as `character(len=30)`, and all my google searches drown in general pages about Fortran character arrays...

Comment: Nvm: apparently one needs to specify both start and end index. `fname(1:1)` did the trick =)

Comment: OK, I'll mark this as the answer to "how do I troubleshoot this" - `iachar()` was the tool I needed. I started scraping away all the other things I did and just looking at these file names, and suddenly it worked! Carefully adding stuff back, I found an off-by-one error on a completely unrelated matrix of reals, that should have given me a segfault hours ago. Instead, it set the last two characters in my file names to `''`... Thanks for helping me find this!

Comment: OK, I'm frustrated enough that I need to stress this: this is the first time in my life that I have ever *wished* for the computer to just throw me a segfault...

Comment: Check your compiler documentation and figure out how to switch on run-time array-bounds checking.  Also, if your code is at all non-modular, how to switch on compile-time procedure argument matching.  For historical reasons default Fortran compilation usually switches on neither and they are a fruitful source of often-confusing errors such as the one you are currently struggling with.

Comment: I'm using `gfortran`, so with the option `-fcheck-bounds` I got an out-of-bounds error instead. Is there a good way to switch on all (or the recommended) such checks, similar to `-Wall` for warnings? I'm skimming through the man page, but I'm not finding anything useful...

Comment: If I could give you more rep for your comment about array-bounds checking I would - turning that on found a gzillion of other problems I had as well... Thanks a lot!

Comment: The `character*n` form is still in the standard, but it is obsolescent.  (Forms for other types like `real*n` were never in the standard.)